# Skip some lines in file reading

Tags: c++

I want to put 2 columns from a 2-column file into objects to do some math.How can i simply say to the computer "Hey, don't start doing math from the first line of the file but instead do math after the line that has the hash-tag on it". I have an example of the file below:

[image]

Comment: Easy if you [read line by line](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: `std::getline()` into a `std::string`. Then look for the # and use `std::istringstream` to get the values out of the string

Answer (score 0):

Read the first line and ignore it. Read the other lines and process them:

```
using std::getline;
using std::string;
using std::ifstream;

string line;
ifstream file("FILENAME");
getline(file, line);
while(getline(file, line)) {
    process(line);
}
```